# How many bytes can I send via POST / GET?

Tags: php, android, web-services, post, get

I've a simple Android app, which takes a picture from the camera, then converts the image to Base64 characters. Then I send this String to a webservice, and webservices converts this Base64 to a binary file, then the image is finally saved on the server.

However, its working on small pictures, but I guess this is not possible to do with a video or a high resolution image.

Do you guys know where's the limit? I guess it's directly related to how many chars you can send via parameters on the request but couldn't find anything about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read the following standard you can see that there shouldn't be a limit, but the web servers might have (a quote from here [http 1.1](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2616.html))

```
The HTTP protocol does not place any a priori limit on the length of
a URI. Servers MUST be able to handle the URI of any resource they
serve, and SHOULD be able to handle URIs of unbounded length if they
provide GET-based forms that could generate such URIs. A server
SHOULD return 414 (Request-URI Too Long) status if a URI is longer
than the server can handle
```

As far as I know the limit for apache is 4000 characters long for a GET request

For POSTs there shouldn't be any limit

Comment: Thanks. I guess if it crashes it will be something related on web server.